# how to make json on iphone using jquery 

Tags: jquery, iphone, json

i can use this to make a json on web browser:

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(array);
```

but , it has not a object named "JSON" on iphone ,

so what can i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check at the SBJSon library [here](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/)

It has two facility method:

- one operating on NSObject (`- (NSString *)JSONRepresentation`) to transform them into a Json NSString
- one operating on NSString (`- (id)JSONValue`) to create NSArray or NSDictionary from a Json NSString.